# Angular2 - how to setup radio button option to use a dynamic value

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular2-template

I have a `Proposal` component where the user selects a value from a radio button:

```
  public salutations = [
    { value: 0, display: 'Mr & Mrs' },
    { value: 1, display: 'Mrs' },
    { value: 2, display: 'Ms'},
    { value: 3, display: 'Mr'},
    { value: 4, display: 'proposal.first_name'}
  ];
```

In each case, the selected option is stored in the `Proposal.greeting` field. I don't store the value, but the actual display property.

```
  <div *ngFor="let salutation of salutations">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="salutation" [(ngModel)]="proposal.salutation" 
        [value]="salutation.display"> <!-- we DO NOT want to store the integer value -->
        {{salutation.display}}
    </label>
  </div>
```

As you can see, when the user selects option 4, the intention is to store the actual name of the proposer (proposal.first_name).

This is because later I have a view that looks like this:

```
<p>Dear {{proposal.greeting}} {{proposal.last_name}},</p>
```

So how can I make that option 4 dynamic (so that when selected it stores the first_name and not the string 'proposal.first_name').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of the quotes around `proposal.firstname` in your TypeScript. Because `salutations` is declared in a `.ts` file, not html, Angular is not going to perform interpolation. Also, you need to tack on a `this.` prefix.

```
public salutations = [
    { value: 0, display: 'Mr & Mrs' },
    { value: 1, display: 'Mrs' },
    { value: 2, display: 'Ms'},
    { value: 3, display: 'Mr'},
    { value: 4, display: this.proposal.first_name} 
  ];
```

See the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ihTriHonzWNODjeUEgzq?p=preview) I put together.

Comment: Thanks, great answer and I can see the punkr works. Problem is, this is used when a new proposal is being created, so at that point 'this.proposal.first_name' has a null value, thus nothing is viewable on screen for option 4.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to make the radio button a child component that has the first_name as an input and outputs which option was selected. Seems a lot of work for such a simple problem!